# Laravel 5 sometimes validation rule

Tags: validation, laravel-5, rules

I want to put data into 2 tables in the database and use rule 'sometimes' in laravel on some variables. But the error appears like this

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'nik' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `bio` (`nik`, `nip`, `nidn`, `id_nipsp`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, , , psp03052018qQT, 2018-05-17 02:40:53, 2018-05-17 02:40:53))

and the data just goes to the user table. what should i do? i change sometimes to nullable also error.

here my code

```html
   public function store(Request $request){ 
        $input= $request->all();
        $validator = Validator::make($input, [
            'nipsp' => 'required|string|unique:user,nipsp',
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'nik' => 'sometimes|unique:bio,nik',
            'nip' => 'sometimes|unique:bio,nip',
            'nidn' => 'sometimes|unique:bio,nidn',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('user/create')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validator);
        }
        $user = User::create($input);
        $bio = new Bio;
        $bio->nik = $request->input('nik');
        $bio->nip = $request->input('nip');
        $bio->nidn = $request->input('nidn');
        $user->bio()->save($bio);
        return redirect('user'); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As column 'nik' cannot be `null` in your DB table than you need `required` rule for `nik` instead of `sometimes`:

```
'nik' => 'required|unique:bio,nik'
```

or you should modify `nik` column in your table adding possibility to set `null` values. For other columns the same.

Comment: ok thankyou Sir, i prefer to modify table than change the rule